# How can I add lines to document every four lines?

Tags: text-processing

I want to add a new line every four lines of a document.

For example:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vw
xyz
```

should become:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl

mno 
pqr
stu
vw

xyz
```

Answer (score 12):

## sed (GNU)

```
sed '0~4G'
```

man sed explains ~ as:

> first ~ step
>   Match every step'th line starting with line first. For example, ``sed -n 1~2p'' will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream, and the address 2~5 will match every fifth line, starting with the second. first can be zero; in this case, sed operates as if it were equal to step. (This is an extension.)

## sed (other)

Short (ugly for 100 lines):

```
sed 'n;n;n;G'
```

**Or**, Count new lines:

```
sed -e 'p;s/.*//;H;x;/\n\{4\}/{g;p};x;d'
```

Or, to be more portable, written as (remove comments for some versions of sed) :

```
sed -e '             # Start a sed script.
         p            # Whatever happens later, print the line.
         s/.*//       # Clean the pattern space.
         H            # Add **one** newline to hold space.
         x            # Get the hold space to examine it, now is empty.
         /\n\{4\}/{   # Test if there are 4 new lines counted.
             g        # Erase the newline count.
             p        # Print an additional new line.
           }          # End the test.
         x            # match the `x` done above.
         d            # don't print anything else. Re-start.
       '              # End sed script.
```

## awk

Probably:

```
awk '1 ; NR % 4 == 0 {printf"\n"} '
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph A `s/older/other/` done, Better?

Answer (score 10):

try this command:

```
awk ' {print;} NR % 4 == 0 { print ""; }'
```

Comment: In case you want to understand what the above is doing: awk will process your file line by line. It will `print` each line. If the line number `NR` is divisible by 4 with no remainder (`% 4 == 0`) then print a blank line

Comment: You can replace `{print;}` with `1;` for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -e 'n;n;n;G'

 perl -pe '$. % 4 or s/$/\n/' 

 perl -lpe '$\ = $. % 4 ? "\n"  : "\n\n"'
```

Where we change the output record separator every fourth line.

Comment: the sed one assumes the input has a number of line that is multiple of 4 (or that you're using GNU `sed` and POSIXLY_CORRECT is not in the environment). You should use `sed 'n;n;n;G'` here.

Comment: Yes that is correct, hadn't realized it.